# Using auto or decltype for Function Pointer Types in C++ primer

Tags: c++

> C++ primer, 6.7 pointer to functions Using auto or decltype for Function Pointer Types
>
> If we know which function(s) we want to return, we can use decltype to simplify
> writing a function pointer return type. For example, assume we have two functions, both of which return a string::size_type and have two const string&
> parameters. We can write a third function that takes a string parameter and returns a pointer to one of these two functions as follows:

```
string::size_type sumLength(const string&, const string&);
string::size_type largerLength(const string&, const string&);
// depending on the value of its string parameter,
// getFcn returns a pointer to sumLength or to largerLength
decltype(sumLength) *getFcn(const string &);
```

I don't understand "depending on the value of its string parameter, `getFcn` returns a pointer to `sumLength` or to `largerLength`".
How do I know the pointer function returns point to `sumLength` or `largerLength`?

Comment: *"How do I know the pointer funtion returns point to sumLength or largerLength?"* - Because it says that is what the function was written to do. Its  a hypothetical function that *could be written* to return one of those two pointers.

Comment: I wonder why the book doesn’t shows the usage of *auto* here? I can‘t imagine how to use it in this context as alternative to *decltype*. Does the heading probably refer to the example with the trailing return-type, the section before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passage is saying you can define getFcn as such

```
typedef decltype(sumLength) func_type;
func_type* getFcn(const string& s)
{
    if (s.size() < 1000) // magic number
        return sumLength;
    else
        return largerLength;
}
```

And you can call it like

```
string str1, str2;

// calls either sumLength or largerLength with str1, str2 
// depending on str1's size
auto i = getFcn(str1)(str1, str2);
```